# Kafka/Streams Consumer Scaling Architecture

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Posting this question to discuss best approaches/practices for scaling out kafka-consumers. Here's my use-case -

We have multiple (more than a million) applications pushing data to kafka - each application has one assigned kafka topic with six partitions. Our need is to process the data pushed by applications in near real-time - we need to push a callback once processing is done and this has to be per kafka record. So, the naive approach is to spawn one kafka-consumer per partition. But this can get expensive, especially when some applications donot produce data in a contiguous sequence. So to address this, we decided to spawn consumers subscribing to multiple topics (spring-kafka regex matching topic pattern) -  we can have some arbitrary number of consumers subscribe to topics and let kafka framework handle partition distribution amongst available consumers; all the consumers will be belonging to one unique consumer-group.

The approach seem to work under normal workload/traffic-patterns but there are some obvious shortcomings that we would like to address  -

- One slow consumer can potentially affect overall consumer lag, especially when record processing varies from application to application and consumers are subscribing to multiple topics.
- Scale-in/scale-out strategies.
- Individual consumer health-checking - identifying zombies ?

Comment: `One slow consumer can potentially affect overall consumer lag` - what is the expected processing duration, a few milliseconds, seconds or minutes?
do you need to process messages on consumer from different topics in the same manner, or differently?

no need to start new app instance on consumer side per each partition, instead use the following properties: `num.stream.threads` for kafka-streams or `concurrency` for spring-kafka, in order to parallel consuming

Comment: We have this use-case of adding exponential back-off on re-tries. So, when record processing fails, we route it to a different topic and the consumer for topic-2 need to process it with some back-off (calculate time delta between message publish timestamp and current time-stamp). Well, my question actually is how to adjust concurrency settings.

Comment: One option is to have separate set of consumers per processing type(slow/fast) and then derive custom metric like calculating lag in terms of message processing - time delta between record publish timestamp to current-system-timestamp. We can then use this metric to scale-out independent consumer-groups.

Comment: How do you plan on managing offsets/duplicate records of those independent consumer groups? That isn't going to solve any lag issues, and will effectively DDOS the downstream services. If the different groups are different sets of topics, then you'll still need to "hand-off" subscription states and offset numbers to those groups somehow as you scale

Comment: Sorry, I think my comment was not clear. Our processing varies from topic-to-topic. For example consumer-groups subscribing to topics that need processing with back-off will be progressing at a slower pace than those consumer-groups which process without any back-off. Its possible to derive custom lag metrics per consumer-group. We can then make use of these metrics to scale-out perhaps ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer About the comment you made -`How do you plan on managing offsets/duplicate records of those independent consumer groups` - shouldn't this be taken care by consumer-group mechanism ?...consumers subscribing to certain topic classes will always share the same group-id. Off-course, at times we can have over-provisioned or ideal consumers and am still looking at a reasonable approach for gracefully handling such ideal consumers.

Comment: What I meant - Say you have group1 with topics t1 and t2, then you "scale out" t2 into a new group2. In that case, group2 will start from your `auto.offset.reset` setting and have no connection to the previous group1 values.

Comment: We will not be creating a new group...will only add new consumer threads to current-group subscribing to specific topic class. Scaling has to match group-id's.